How to build CentOS kernel RPM with the kernel-firmware package?
I am trying to build a custom kernel RPM for CentOS 6.10. Normally I can build a kernel with rpmbuild -ba file.spec, which does produce the kernel in this case, but it builds with a missing dependency for kernel-firmware that I think it supposed to also be build by this SPEC file.
There is a build option in the SPEC file --with firmware, but this does not produce the necessary RPM dependency.
rpmbuild -ba --with firmare kernel.spec
How do I build this RPM dependency?
Here is the exact error message when I try to build:
rpm -ivh kernel-2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.local.i686.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        kernel-firmware >= 2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.local is needed by kernel-2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.local.i686

